# Is there a straight forward way to unit test CRUD/FLS checks in Apex?

Tags: apex, security

I know this is a question which has been discussed earlier, but I'm unable to find a convincing RECENT answer anywhere.

I checked this [How do you Apex Unit Test Object(CRUD)/Field(FLS) Permissions in an Org Portable manner?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1367/how-do-you-apex-unit-test-objectcrud-fieldfls-permissions-in-an-org-portable) but that question is also bit older, wondering if things have changed on the platform.

So, is it possible to properly unit test CRUD/FLS checks without having to depend on Profiles or Users created out side the unit test setup (i.e by creating all the data required for the test, within the test setup)?

Comment: I think this would be better if you commented on the original question and voted it up. This is very likely to be closed as a duplicated.

Comment: I've seen this tested before by creating a Chatter External User which has limited access to objects and the profile exists in the org. You then use System.runAs for that user, take a look at this for an example, https://github.com/financialforcedev/df12-apex-enterprise-patterns/blob/master/df12/src/classes/SObjectSelector.cls#L133